# How to query in solr using facet value

Tags: solr, facet, solrj

I have following facet value-

> facetname1 -value11 ,value12, value 13
>
> facetname2 - value21, value22 , value 23

User has selected values value12, value23 from the UI page.I just have these values and I want to query solr using these facet values..
From SolrJ API's how can I find the name of facet from its value and how can I query it from solr indexes..
Thanks in advance

More Info

```
 <lst name="facetname1">
<int name="value11">57270</int>
<int name="value12">30125</int>
<int> name="value13">19552</int>
</lst>
```

I can see this information by typing http://localhost:8080/requesthandlername
That requesthandler contain name of each facets

Answer (score 0):

> From SolrJ API's how can I find the name of facet from its value

No, it's up to you to keep track of the facet fields and values. You should submit both the facet field and the selected facet value.

> how can I query it from solr

If you mean how to "turn" facets into queries, use [filter queries](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq). In SolrJ, use the `setFilterQueries` method ([many examples](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%2bsolrj%20%2bsetfilterqueries))

Comment: Thank you for the reply mauricio. Is there any way to get the field value from field name from solr config files. Because I know that information is stored in my solr. But I am not able to grab it from UI

Comment: For example,can i do facet.getValues() and checking whether that value is present in that particular facet or not

Comment: @user598159: you should submit both field name and field value.